# Too many index.php files running and eating up all memory

Tags: performance, plugin-w3-total-cache, memory

I have wordpress site installed on dedicated server. From few days I'm experiencing high memory consumption on this cpanel account and it is slowing my wordpress site

[image: High Physical Memory usage]

Then I examined Process Manager through my WHM Account and I found many index.php processes were running and consuming all memory.

[image: Many index.php processes]

Then I killed all processes of career99 account through process manager from my whm account and Memory Usage also reduced.

[image: Memory Usage Reduced]

Why too many index.php are running ?, How can I check what is the cause here ?.
I have tried Plugin Profiler but didn't find any issue with any plugin. I am using W3 Total cache plugin on my site.

Any Suggestion ? Please help me to solve this.

Comment: This might have to do more with your web server configuration in regards to PHP, could you elaborate on it?

Comment: Take a look at https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with any server configurations you want to setup some sort of safety to avoid this kind of processes running infinitely.

PHP already provides you some tools to do it, and it's pretty easy. 
- [exit_on_timeout](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.exit-on-timeout)
- [max_execution_time](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time)

You will need to find a safe spot for what you are running inside of your WordPress installation.

---

If you want more detailed information you might want to do this same question on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/)